# $\lim _{x\to \infty }x\log\left(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\right)$

Tags: limits

Is there any trick to solve this?

$\lim _{x\to \infty }x\log\left(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}-\log\left(x\right)\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} (1+\sqrt{1+x^2}-\log x )= \infty
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the limit in question is actually

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\,x\left(\log\left(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)-\log(x))\right)$$

Proceeding accordingly, we have

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)-\log(x)&=\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\right)\\\\
&=\log\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}+\frac1x \right)\\\\
&=\log\left(1+\frac1x +O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac1x+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\,x\left(\log\left(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)-\log(x))\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+O\left(\frac1x\right)\right)=1$$

Comment: thank you very much, now I understand everything :)

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

HINT: observe that $$\log(1+\sqrt{1+x^2})-\log(x)=0$$ for $x$ tends to infinity.